# Pandas - duration where parameter is "1"

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am new to python and pandas and I am trying to solve this problem:

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
timestamp       par_1 par_2
1486873206867   0     0
1486873207039   NaN   0
1486873207185   0     NaN
1486873207506   1     0
1486873207518   NaN   NaN
1486873207831   1     0
1486873208148   0     NaN
1486873208469   0     1
1486873208479   1     NaN
1486873208793   1     NaN
1486873208959   NaN   1
1486873209111   1     NaN
1486873209918   NaN   0
1486873210075   0     NaN
```

I want to know the total duration of the event "1" for each parameter. (Parameters can only be NaN, 1 or 0)

I have already tried

`df['duration_par_1'] = df.groupby(['par_1'])['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())`

but for further processing, I only need the duration of the event "1" to be in new columns and then that duration needs to be in every row of the new column so that it looks like this:

```
timestamp       par_1 par_2  duration_par_1  duration_par2
1486873206867   0     0      2238            1449
1486873207039   NaN   0      2238            1449
1486873207185   0     NaN    2238            1449
1486873207506   1     0      2238            1449
1486873207518   NaN   NaN    2238            1449
1486873207831   1     0      2238            1449
1486873208148   0     NaN    2238            1449
1486873208469   0     1      2238            1449
1486873208479   1     NaN    2238            1449
1486873208793   1     NaN    2238            1449
1486873208959   NaN   1      2238            1449
1486873209111   1     NaN    2238            1449
1486873209918   NaN   0      2238            1449
1486873210075   0     NaN    2238            1449
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need multiple values of `par` columns by difference of datetimes, because not exist another values like `0`, `1` and `NaN` in data:

```
d = df['timestamp'].diff()
df1 = df.filter(like='par')
#if need duration by some value e.g. by `0`
#df1 = df.filter(like='par').eq(0).astype(int)
s = df1.mul(d, axis=0).sum().astype(int).add_prefix('duration_')

df = df.assign(**s)
print (df)
        timestamp  par_1  par_2  duration_par_1  duration_par_2
0   1486873206867    0.0    0.0            1110             487
1   1486873207039    NaN    0.0            1110             487
2   1486873207185    0.0    NaN            1110             487
3   1486873207506    1.0    0.0            1110             487
4   1486873207518    NaN    NaN            1110             487
5   1486873207831    1.0    0.0            1110             487
6   1486873208148    0.0    NaN            1110             487
7   1486873208469    0.0    1.0            1110             487
8   1486873208479    1.0    NaN            1110             487
9   1486873208793    1.0    NaN            1110             487
10  1486873208959    NaN    1.0            1110             487
11  1486873209111    1.0    NaN            1110             487
12  1486873209918    NaN    0.0            1110             487
13  1486873210075    0.0    NaN            1110             487
```

**Explanation**:

First get difference of `timestamp` column:

```
print (df['timestamp'].diff())
0       NaN
1     172.0
2     146.0
3     321.0
4      12.0
5     313.0
6     317.0
7     321.0
8      10.0
9     314.0
10    166.0
11    152.0
12    807.0
13    157.0
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
```

Select all columns with string `par` by [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
print (df.filter(like='par'))
    par_1  par_2
0     0.0    0.0
1     NaN    0.0
2     0.0    NaN
3     1.0    0.0
4     NaN    NaN
5     1.0    0.0
6     0.0    NaN
7     0.0    1.0
8     1.0    NaN
9     1.0    NaN
10    NaN    1.0
11    1.0    NaN
12    NaN    0.0
13    0.0    NaN
```

Multiple filtered columns by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) by `d`:

```
print (df1.mul(d, axis=0))
    par_1  par_2
0     NaN    NaN
1     0.0    0.0
2     0.0    0.0
3   321.0    0.0
4     0.0    0.0
5   313.0    0.0
6     0.0    0.0
7     0.0  321.0
8    10.0    0.0
9   314.0    0.0
10    0.0  166.0
11  152.0    0.0
12    0.0    0.0
13    0.0    0.0
```

And `sum` values:

```
print (df1.mul(d, axis=0).sum())
par_1    1110.0
par_2     487.0
dtype: float64
```

Convert to `integer`s and change index by [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add_prefix.html):

```
print (df1.mul(d, axis=0).sum().astype(int).add_prefix('duration_'))
duration_par_1    1110
duration_par_2     487
dtype: int32
```

Last create new columns by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html).

Comment: Thanks! Using the fact that the value cannot be higher than 1 is brilliant.

Comment: @cnila - Yes, I was happy with this fact too, solution is easier ;)